# Mac Catalina apache2 Connection refused

Tags: mac-osx, httpd, apache2

Since the new Mac OSX update my apache2 broke.

I followed [this guide](https://getgrav.org/blog/macos-catalina-apache-multiple-php-versions) on how to setup apache2 on the new OSX, but I still get "Connection Refused" error when I try to open `localhost` in my browser.

Anyone have any idea why? I've made sure that my httpd.conf has no syntax errors, and that it listens to port 80: `Listen *:80`.

My error logs are not printing anything except for that I've restarted the service.

The server is up and running according to `ps -aef | grep httpd` which outputs:

```
   0   180     1   0 11:05am ??         0:00.48 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 34955   180   0 11:15am ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 34956   180   0 11:15am ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 34957   180   0 11:15am ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 34958   180   0 11:15am ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 34959   180   0 11:15am ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 35366   180   0 11:15am ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 36887   180   0 11:15am ??         0:00.00 /usr/local/opt/httpd/bin/httpd -D FOREGROUND
  502 98180 95819   0 11:52am ttys000    0:00.00 grep httpd
```

And `lsof -i:80` outputs:

```
COMMAND   PID               USER   FD   TYPE             DEVICE SIZE/OFF NODE NAME
httpd   34955 jonathanohrstromNY    4u  IPv6 0xc72c500a38f5aabd      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   34956 jonathanohrstromNY    4u  IPv6 0xc72c500a38f5aabd      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   34957 jonathanohrstromNY    4u  IPv6 0xc72c500a38f5aabd      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   34958 jonathanohrstromNY    4u  IPv6 0xc72c500a38f5aabd      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   34959 jonathanohrstromNY    4u  IPv6 0xc72c500a38f5aabd      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   35366 jonathanohrstromNY    4u  IPv6 0xc72c500a38f5aabd      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
httpd   36887 jonathanohrstromNY    4u  IPv6 0xc72c500a38f5aabd      0t0  TCP *:http (LISTEN)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, chrome was trying to use SSL to connect to localhost. Disabled it and now it works fine!

Comment: Give more details on how you solved pls? Looks like I have similar issue.